# Can I fit distribution of pixel intensity?

Tags: independence

I have an image and I want to plot the histogram of pixel intensity. The distribution seems a Poisson distribution (long tail). Can I fit this distribution using matlab function `[lambdahat,lambdaci] = poissfit(data)` and consider the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) of the parameter of the Poisson distribution, λ given the data `data` and 95% confidence intervals in lambdaci ? My concern is that the pixel intensities are not indipendent values...

The histogram of pixel intensity is for estimate what is the most likely pixel intensity in the image to occur. I am dealing with physiological measurements such as a brain map of cerebral blood flow. I want to know what is the value of cerebral blood flow in a specific area of a brain, for example temporal area.

Comment: It's likely you can estimate a Poisson parameter and see whether it's a useful description of the distribution, but the lack of independence means you cannot trust any confidence interval computed by software that doesn't account for the dependence.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your answer. Do you know how to deal with dependent data ?

Comment: You have to formulate a probability model of dependence.  Because you haven't told us anything about your application, there's nothing specific anyone can tell you.

Comment: I think a more reasonable approach might be to consider each pixel as a variable and consider the (dependent) distributions of pixels across multiple images. The distribution of pixels within a single image does not make sense to me for statistical inference. The image is the image. I see no room for inference.

Comment: @whuber, I modified my post. Now I hope that the application is clearer.

Comment: Thank you.  I cannot perceive any connection between this application and what you are asking, however.  Could you explain how an MLE of $\lambda$ would help with characterizing "specific areas"?  It's unclear how this specific area might be related to the "brain map" you refer to.

Comment: Because I want to know the value of that physiological parameter that is most likely to occur and so that represents that area. I could make the mean of the parameter values in that area. However, characterizing intensity distribution would let me know also its confidence interval (since I do not have other images). @whuber does that make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the underlying thing you are trying to model? If you want to aggregate intensity into some number, why not simply add intensities in different pixels?

If you want to model the change in the distribution of intensities, perhaps it is better to consider a model of many correlated variables , one per each pixel (e.g. each pixel is a binomial random variable with fixed N (number of levels it can take), and spatially correlated probability), and then you can compare the changes in the distributions at pixel level. Aggregating this into a histogram seems superfluous.

---

*ADDENDUM*

Still not quite sure what the histogram is for. Let say this this needed to calibrate some sort of equipment, e.g. like camera brightness adjustment. The thing about histograms is that it is meant to represent independent variable distribution. One way I can think about creating such a thing is by bootstrapping. So instead of generating histogram from all the pixels, you can posit the histogram definition as 'distribution of intensities for a randomly selected pixel'. Then you select randomly, with repetition, from your image/images. And that will give you a histogram. Provided your selection is random any spatial correlations should not matter anymore. They will affect the result, but successive draws will be no more or less correlated than all the other draws. Such a histogram will then be free from 'independence' concerns

Comment: sorry I do not understand your answer... do you mean to consider many images and then consider the distribution of each pixel distribution given by many images ?

Comment: @HelpNeederStudent, what are you trying to do? Are you trying to measure the overall intensity then add the pixels up. If you are measuring changes in distribution of intensity, then why do you need the histogram? Presumably this destroys all your spatial information. Or are you trying to extract the probability distribution for intensity of a randomly selected single pixel

Comment: Why do you need the histogram? What is it meant to represent?

Comment: I need the histogram because I need the distribution of pixels intensity. I want to extract the pixel intensity that has the highest number of counts (so the lambda of the Poisson if it has a Poisson distribution) and its confidence interval. However I do not know how to deal with dependent data...

Comment: @HelpNeederStudent, I added a section. Is this helpful?

Comment: It sounds to me a smart solution. I am going to try and let you know. Thank you @Cryo .

Comment: Anyway, I have edited my post to clarify what the histogram is for. I hope it is clearer now...